Can I stop and dispose `TcpListener` after accepting my only expected client?
I tried this on Windows, and the client appears to continue working, but I want to understand if this behavior is guaranteed or just a fluke:
using (var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 34346)) {
    listener.Start();

    // client
    Task.Run(async () => {
        using var client = new TcpClient();
        await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, 34346);
        await using var stream = client.GetStream();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        stream.WriteByte(42);
    });
    
    using var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

    listener.Stop();
    listener.Dispose();
    log.LogInformation("Disposed listener");

    await using var stream = client.GetStream();
    log.LogInformation("{Byte}", stream.ReadByte());
}

Prints:
Disposed listener
42


Sort of relevant, but you can not dispose TcpClient and continue to use NetworkStream. E.g. if before logging the byte you call client.Dispose(), the ReadByte call will throw ObjectDisposedException

I mean sure you could, that's the basics of TCP..
The listener is just there to setup and hand-off the actual connection.
But why would want to?  If you think it adds security, well you're not necessarily wrong...but
What happens if the client gets disconnected? They would be un-able to re-connect.  What happens if somebody besides your expected client connects?

In my case none of the issues apply as I use it to communicate with a virtual machine running on the same host over a network private to the host and the VM.
